# How do I get end of the string Scrapy?

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm trying to get full mail but it's taking only 1st. I'm not getting **.com** Here is the HTML

```
<div class="email-show tr1" rel="hello@example.com" xpath="1">
              <div class="left tr1"><i class="fa fa-at"></i></div>
              <div class="right tr1 noselect">
                <span>hello@example</span>.com              </div>
            </div>
```

And this is what I wrote

```
response.xpath('//*[@class="right tr1 noselect"]/span/text()').extract_first()
```

Output

```
hallo@example
```

Please point me what wrong I'm doing in here. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You realize there's no `.com` in the `<span>` tag? The `.com` bit is in the `<div>`.

Comment: yes I do but how to add them together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply do it using

```
"".join(line for line in response.xpath('//*[contains(@class, "email-show")]//text()').extract())
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
response.xpath('//*[@class="email-show tr1"]/@rel').extract_first()
```